# Receive SMS Programmatically

Tags: sms

I need to send and receive SMS messages, but not on a phone.  Sending is somewhat easy, as there are oodles of gateways that can be used.  The challenge that I'm running into is handling responses received.

Can anyone point in me in the right direction of services or devices that can handle 2 way SMS short of an actual phone.

Comment: And what exactly do you want to receieve your messages with, *besides* a phone?  A PC?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Programmatic SMS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269/programmatic-sms)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Receive SMS messages by web application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/526046/receive-sms-messages-by-web-application)

Answer (score 1):

[SMS GATEWAY ME](http://smsgateway.me) is an android app that you can download for free.

I like it because it's free and easy to use. All you do is send a HTTP post to their server and it sends out a message from your phone.

You can set up rules on the site to get it to forward incoming messages to your server using HTTP / Email as well.

Answer (score 0):

There are some 2 way SMS gateways out there. A quick search found this one: http://www.txtimpact.com/api.asp all I did was google for 2-way sms gateway.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that uses Wammu under Linux:

- http://www.techytalk.info/send-receive-sms-using-gsm-modem-phone-ubuntu/

Here's another link:

- http://www.developershome.com/sms/smsLinux.asp

And:

- http://www.developershome.com/sms/

Good luck!